# jQuery AJAX not recognizing updated div classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am creating a basic checklist site, and using jQuery's $.ajax() to send the check/uncheck requests to the server. When a user clicks the check or uncheck buttons, jQuery gets the validation token and id from the parent list item div, determines what the current state of the item is (checked/unchecked) and sends the action, and on success uses toggleClass() to update the div and reflect the current state through CSS.

The backend is working just fine, but the trouble I am having is when I try to uncheck a checked item jQuery does not recognize the newly toggled classes and proceeds as though it were a check action instead.

I am using .on(), and binding to the low level element .main-content, and indicating the buttons as child elements. In this case though jQuery continues to see an .unchecked class even once it has been checked, so every uncheck attempt still registers as a check action.

The closest I've come is binding the action to the buttons directly with on() instead of as child elements. jQuery will then see the list element's new .checked class and send an uncheck action via AJAX, but as soon it gets to AJAX's success function, the class on the list element reverts immediately to .unchecked, and then the success function toggles it back to .checked.

One more clarification - The check & uncheck buttons are separate html elements and are hidden/shown via CSS with `display:none` based on the list item class.

List Item HTML:

```
<li class="list-item unchecked" id="6">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="xR4vNWKEnCQMQKQZHb1xchApfhPOnMHHBGVMmV1Z">
  <div class="item-body">
    <h4 class="item-name">Item Name</h4>
    <div class="col-sm-4 actions-col">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-check-unchecked">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-check-checked">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".main-content").on("click", ".btn-check-unchecked, .btn-check-checked", function() {
  var listItem = $(this).closest('.list-item');
  var token = listItem.find('input[name=_token]').val();
  var id = listItem.attr('id');
  var unchecked = listItem.hasClass('unchecked');
  var checkType = unchecked ? 'check' : 'uncheck';
  listItem.addClass('pending');
  $.ajax({
    url: '/itemactions/check',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      _token: token,
      itemId: id,
      checkType: checkType
    },
    success: function() {
      listItem.toggleClass('checked');
      listItem.toggleClass('unchecked');
      listItem.removeClass('pending');
    },
    error: function() {
      listItem.removeClass('pending');
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Any idea how to persist the checked class so jQuery will recognize it and toggle the classes properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I've read your issue correctly, it appears to be working fine in this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/v21qf0vq/). However, I am mocking the ajax call and using simple CSS. Is it possible that the ajax call to uncheck is failing? Or, do you have CSS that may be masking something?

Comment: Your list item has two check buttons. Wouldn't it make more sense to attach the state of the clicked check button on the actual element (opposed to the list item) ?  Here is an [revised and shortened version](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZwWeK) of your code.

Comment: @Mikey the class is on the list item instead of just the buttons so that the whole item can change color instead of just the check buttons. The buttons are set to `display: none` in the CSS when the item state is opposite. @WonderGrub the ajax call is successful, it's just reverting to unchecked immediately before executing the success function.

Comment: WonderGrub & @Mikey you were both right. I had CSS associated with having two check buttons that was overriding the ajax actions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Wondergrub and @Mikey - the real problem was I had CSS associated with having two check buttons in the html that was overriding ajax's attempts to toggle the classes. I combined the two buttons into one and fixed the CSS and voila! Solved.